# In Apache Spark Writing a Dataframe to Hive table in Java

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to accomplish a simple things of "writing a dataframe to Hive table", below is the code written in Java. I'm using Cloudera VM with no changes.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String master = "local[*]";

    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
            .builder().appName(JsonToHive.class.getName())
            //.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://localhost:50070/user/hive/warehouse/")
            .enableHiveSupport().master(master).getOrCreate();

    SparkContext context = sparkSession.sparkContext();
    context.setLogLevel("ERROR");

    SQLContext sqlCtx = sparkSession.sqlContext();
    Dataset<Row> rowDataset = sqlCtx.jsonFile("employees.json");
    rowDataset.printSchema();
    rowDataset.registerTempTable("employeesData");

    Dataset<Row> firstRow = sqlCtx.sql("select employee.firstName, employee.addresses from employeesData");
    firstRow.show();

    sparkSession.catalog().listTables().select("*").show();

    firstRow.write().mode() saveAsTable("default.employee");
    sparkSession.close();

}
```

I have create the managed table in HIVE using the HQL ,

```
 CREATE TABLE employee ( firstName STRING, lastName STRING, addresses  ARRAY < STRUCT < street:STRING,  city:STRING, state:STRING > > )  STORED AS PARQUET;
```

I'm reading a simple JSON file for data from "employees.json"

```
{"employee":{"firstName":"Neil","lastName":"Irani","addresses":[{"street":"36th","city":"NYC","state":"Ny"},{"street":"37th","city":"NYC","state":"Ny"},{"street":"38th","city":"NYC","state":"Ny"}]}}
```

It says "Table `default`.`employee` already exists.;" and it does not append the content. How to append the content to the hive table ??

If I set the mode("append"), it does not complain but it does not write the content as well ..

firstRow.write().mode("append") saveAsTable("default.employee");

Any help will be appreciated... thanks.

```
+-------------+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|         name|database|description|tableType|isTemporary|
+-------------+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|     employee| default|       null|  MANAGED|      false|
|employeesdata|    null|       null|TEMPORARY|       true|
+-------------+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

UPDATE

/usr/lib/hive/conf/hive-site.xml was not in the classpath so it was not reading the tables, after adding it in the classpath it worked fine ... Since I was running from IntelliJ I have this problem .. in production the spark-conf folder will  have link to hive-site.xml ...

Comment: you need to create HiveContext                                                   
       HiveContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(ctx.sc());

Comment: I think the fundamental problem is I'm not able to connect to LOCAL-hive, the below call returns 
"Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'employee' not found in database 'default';"

hiveContext.sql("SHOW COLUMNS FROM default.employee").show();
sqlCtx.sql("SHOW COLUMNS FROM default.employee").show();

Comment: Setting configuration on HiveContext .. no luck as well ........... hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://localhost:50070/user/hive/warehouse"); hiveContext.sql("SHOW COLUMNS FROM employee").show();

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should be doing [insertInto(String tableName)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#insertInto(java.lang.String)) instead of `saveAsTable(String tableName)`.

```
firstRow.write().mode("append").insertInto("default.employee");
```

Comment: I think the fundamental problem is I'm not able to connect to LOCAL-hive, the below call returns 
"Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'employee' not found in database 'default';"

hiveContext.sql("SHOW COLUMNS FROM default.employee").show();
sqlCtx.sql("SHOW COLUMNS FROM default.employee").show();

Comment: Setting configuration on HiveContext .. no luck as well ........... hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://localhost:50070/user/hive/warehouse");
        hiveContext.sql("SHOW COLUMNS FROM employee").show();

Comment: Did you try just `insertInto("employee")`?

Comment: yes I did no luck .. the actual problem is metastore_db is created in my local drive .. which says that my spark-job did not connect to Hive database at all ...